# Looping through array of objects to pull specific data out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, twitter

I'm building a node express angular twitter status analyzer and I'm trying to figure out how to pull the tex out of it and assign it to one long string for use later.

I'm trying to pull user statuses like this:

```
   client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {params, count:20}, function(error, tweets, response) {
    var jsonObject;
    if (!error) {
      analyze.analyze(tweets);
      }
  });
```

The response looks something like this:

```
    [
  {
    "coordinates": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012",
    "id_str": "240859602684612608",
    "entities": {
      "urls": [
        {
          "expanded_url": "/blog/twitter-certified-products",
          "url": "",
          "indices": [
            52,
            73
          ],
          "display_url": "
        }
      ],
      "hashtags": [

      ],
      "user_mentions": [

      ]
    },
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "text": "Introducing the Twitter Certified Products Program: ",
    "retweet_count": 121,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "id": 240859602684612608,
    "geo": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "user": {
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
      "profile_background_tile": false,
      "name": "Twitter API",
      "profile_image_url": ",
      "created_at": "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007",
      "location": "San Francisco, CA",
      "follow_request_sent": false,
      "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
      "is_translator": false,
      "id_str": "6253282",
      "entities": {
        "url": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "expanded_url": null,
              "url": "",
              "indices": [
                0,
                22
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "description": {
          "urls": [

          ]
        }
      },
```

And my current code looks like this:

```
function analyze(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tweet = data[i]['text'];
    tweet = tweet.replace('#' , '');
    return console.log(tweet);
  }
}

module.exports.analyze = analyze;
```

Currently I get only one tweet in my output from my analyze function. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: response `JSON` is not valid.

Comment: I know it's not JSON. It'seems an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pull out an array with all the twitts texts without `#` you can do:

```
function analyze(data) {
    return data.map(function(item) {
        return item.text.replace('#' , '');
    });
}

module.exports.analyze = analyze;
```

Answer (score 1):

The response you posted is not a valid JSON, could you double check it?

Answer (score 0):

**You are returning console.log()**

Return statements halt execution of the function. Simply remove the return statement like so:

```
function analyze(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tweet = data[i]['text'];
    tweet = tweet.replace('#' , '');
    console.log(tweet);
  }
}

module.exports.analyze = analyze;
```

If you want to return the results of the function, you will have to store them in a variable outside of the for loop, concat it with the tweet each iteration, and return that value.